# Sync two different projects on Django user apps

Tags: python, sql, django, database, synchronization

I have a site www.XXX.com and ın my mind I have a different project such as sis.XXX.org. In theory, I want to use site's users in sis.XXX.org. When someone registers www.XXX.com , this user also should be registered to sis automatically. How can I do that? only user app must be the same for both apps. There are different aims for these projects. No, they are not on the same server. Other project is only an idea now. Django backend is going to be used.

Comment: are those on same server? how do you create account - sql / nosql database?

Comment: use the same database for both app.

Comment: only user app must be the same for both apps. There are different aims for these projects. No, they are not on the same server. Other project is only an idea now. Django backend is going to be used.

Comment: as @Gaurav, use the same db for both apps

Comment: In this approach, there is only one admin site, right ? Can you explain more ? @Anentropic

Comment: no you have two django apps, so two admin sites if you want to.  you can have multiple dbs per django app so they could potentially share one and have others specific to each app.  or maybe you only need one db to run both sites